# "perl -i.bak script.pl *.txt" from powershell prompt using activestate perl and windows 10

Tags: perl, powershell

How to invoke this command from powershell prompt using activestate perl?

```
PS> perl -i.bak script.pl *.txt
```

always gives me an error on the -i flag, then refuses to expand the *.txt

I can get around the *.txt problem.

```
PS> perl -i.bak script.pl (dir *.txt | %{$_.FullName})
```

But, the escaping of '.' for -i flag has me baffled.

This works however:

```
PS> perl -ibak script.pl (dir *.txt | %{$_.FullName})
```

Its just that its kind of annoying to not have the dot in the backup file extension.  So I'm back to wondering how to escape the '.' in powershell.

Comment: As an aside: [This article](http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/running-executables-powershell) provides `showargs.exe`, which can be helpful in troubleshooting PowerShell command-line parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
PS> perl "-i.bak" script.pl (dir *.txt | %{$_.FullName})
```

The key is the quotes around the -i flag including its parameter value.

Comment: You could just use `perl --% -i.bak script.pl *.txt` if you're on `v3`+.  This shuts off the parser